# How to make side by side items using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I wanted to write something wherein i need all confirmations of a graph **side by side** and argue something. How could I do that using Latex and Tikz.

Like i want all graph configurations with 3 edges and pick the one which I wanted how can i do it?
[image: **See the Images side by side and not one below the other how could i don this using tikz**]

Comment: and what you try so far? do you like to have two figures side by side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the graphs as `tikzpicture`s and use the `baseline` option to indicate on which node the pictures should get aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=3mm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,baseline=(c)]
  \node[vertex] (a) at (0,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (b) at (1,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (c) at (2,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (d) at (3,0) {};
  \draw (a) -- node{1} (b)
            -- node{2} (c)
            -- node{3} (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,baseline=(c)]
  \node[vertex] (a) at (0, 0.5) {};
  \node[vertex] (b) at (0,-0.5) {};
  \node[vertex] (c) at (1, 0  ) {};
  \node[vertex] (d) at (2, 0  ) {};
  \draw (a) -- node{1} (c)
            -- node{2} (d)
        (b) -- node[swap]{3} (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can label the edges in the process of making the edges.

Comment: @Jaugust I have modified the answer to show how to label the edges.